# Code Completion for Nightwatch.js in Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA or WebStorm

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, webstorm, nightwatch.js, code-completion

I'm new to JavaScript development. Normally I implement Test Automation with Java with Eclipse. But now we changed to JavaScript and we want to use Nightwatch.js together with Cucumber.js to automate our Blackbox tests.

So, I have to configure my IDE, that I can use Code Completion and "Go To Reference". I tried a lot of things with Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA and WebStorm. But in Eclipse (with Nodeclipse) I can't realize the Code Completion and the "Go To Reference", if I want to jump directly into a function. In IDEA and WebStorm the "Go To Reference" functionality works, but not the whole code completion for Nightwatch.js.

Nightwatch.js methods like `waitForElementVisible()` are not suggested. So it's not a complete code completion.

How can I realize to use the whole code completion feature in one of the given IDEs? Do I have to configure Nightwatch.js in the IDEs? And where I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no completion is possible for this module, unless somebody creates a stub library (d.ts or js) for it. The way is defined is tricky. Let's see what the test typically looks like:

```
module.exports = {
    'suit name': function(client)
    {     
        client.url('https://...')
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000) //not resolved
            ...
```

First, the IDE can't know what '*client*' parameter type is. But, even if we declare it via JSDoc annotation to be '*Nightwatch*', still you won't get any completion, because this function is not defined as a Nightwatch property anywhere in the code. Instead, once the spec module is loaded, function name is passed as a parameter to `loadCommandModule()` function in *node_modules/nightwatch/lib/core/api.js* that, in turn, loads the module by name using `module.call()`. Such properties can't be resolved during static code analysis